# Resize em imagem com PHP

Tags: php

Necessito dar resize em todas as imagens quando for efetuado o compartilhamento no Facebook.
Existem várias imagens de diversos tamanhos na listagem de produtos, porém quando compartilho o link no Facebook, dependendo do tamanho da imagem, o Facebook colocar no box maior de imagem ou no box menor, dependendo do tamanho.
O que necessito fazer, é jogar para a meta OG a imagem com o tamanho alterado.

Encontrei uma função que dá resize, porém ela dá em porcentagem e eu necessito que a imagem seja reajustada para o tamanho exato de 600x315px.

Segue o código:

```
<?php
// Imagem e novo tamanho (em porcentagem)
$filename = '1.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($thumb);

?>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
```

Após isto, necessito jogar a imagem reajustada na meta og.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de usar:

```
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;
```

Mude para:

```
$newwidth = 600;
$newheight = 315;
```

Mas as imagens irão ficar esticadas.

Para pôr na sua meta do facebook:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.urldoseusite.com.br/pasta/onde/ficam/suas/imagens/<?php echo $filename; ?>"/>
```